# Pyspark filter performance 3.0.1 vs 3.1.2

Tags: pyspark

I am running my app locally. I have a dataframe with 3 columns

```
df.show()
+--+---------+--------------+
|ID|      key|           val|
+--+---------+--------------+
|12|COL1_FLAG|         Valid|
|12|COL2_FLAG|         Valid|
|12|COL3_FLAG|Invalid Format|
+--+---------+--------------+

df_filtered = df.filter(col('val').like('Invalid%'))
```

The above filter works fine when my spark version is pointed to 3.0.1. When I point my local spark installation to 3.1.2, the execution hangs at the filter stage. I even tried to change the filter as

```
df_filtered = df.filter(col('val').substr(1,7) == 'Invalid')
```

No change in behavior. Am I doing something wrong here or is there a better way to implement this filter?

The explain() on 3.1.2 is failing with the below error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.api.python.PythonSQLUtils.explainString.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$Lambda$949/1910987899.get$Lambda(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/2088051243.invokeStatic_LL_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/112061925.linkToTargetMethod(LambdaForm$MH)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$Lambda$951/1279057069.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$Lambda$1229/1925318585.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:406)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:359)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$Lambda$951/1279057069.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChild$2(TreeNode.scala:386)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$4(TreeNode.scala:438)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$Lambda$1238/1680937321.apply(Unknown Source)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$Lambda$26/632587706.apply(Unknown Source)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:438)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$Lambda$1229/1925318585.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:406)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:359)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:323)
```

Comment: Run this command `df_filtered.explain()` to each version and update your question

Comment: Updated my question with explain plan from 3.1.2

Comment: OutOfMemory to execute `explain` method, I've never seen something like this

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue.
Set `spark.sql.constraintPropagation.enabled` to `false`